# Issues with including jquery plugin (jlembed). Conflicts with namespaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, namespaces

I'm am trying to get [jlembed](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jlembed) to work but I constantly get errors in chrome debugger. I tried all of [THIS](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries#Overriding_the_.24-function) solutions but had no luck. Which is the correct way to include jquery and jquery-plugin? Because I tried putting jQuery first, last.

Here is one of my src code versions:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jlembed.js"></script>  

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $("#playerDiv").jlEmbed({ //here is the error (debugger)
         id : 'player1',
         youtube : 'Cw2HAD9A_rw',
         format : 'swfobject',
         autoplay : 'no',
         youtubechromeless : 'no',
         youtubedisplay : true
    });
});

</script>
```

and ther error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function
(anonymous function)
jQuery.jQuery.extend.readyjquery-latest.js:447
jQuery.DOMContentLoaded
```

EDIT2: Answer:

I found the correct syntax based on [THIS](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jlembed).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jlembed.js"></script>  

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       //jQuery("").hide();
     });

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $("#playerDiv").jlEmbed({
         id : 'player1',
         youtube : 'Cw2HAD9A_rw',
         format : 'swfobject',
         autoplay : 'no',
         youtubechromeless : 'no',
         youtubedisplay : true
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: jQuery definitely has to come first. What is the error that you get?

Comment: hey, I edited my question with the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you call noConflict. then use jQuery as the document ready. and then use the normal $ jquery selector once again on $("#playerDiv")/

try changing that $ to jQuery as well.

Comment: heh, I just edited my question with this solution (posted 2 seconds after your answer). Where were you before :( tnx anyway

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you are actually including jlEmbed AFTER jQuery, but BEFORE the jQuery(document).ready script.

Does your copy of jlEmbed reside at the same location as the page you're using it on? -

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jlembed.js"></script>
```

Try inserting the full path to jlEmbed instead of a relative path.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jlembed.com/latest.js"></script>
```

Comment: I found the soulution. Actually it was on your site but I was doing something wrong. I edited my question with solution after I fixed it. Tnx anyway :D

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this solves the problem, because we don't know the error that you get:

1. Put jQuery first:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jlembed.js"></script>
   ```
2. `$("#playerDiv").jlEmbed({...})` has to go into the callback too!

   ```
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       $("#playerDiv").jlEmbed({
            id : 'player1',
            youtube : 'Cw2HAD9A_rw',
            format : 'swfobject',
            autoplay : 'no',
            youtubechromeless : 'no',
            youtubedisplay : true
       });
   });
   ```

   Otherwise `$("#playerDiv")` will try to find the element with ID `#playerDiv` before it is created.

Comment: I edited my question with your soulition but I still get the error. I edited that also.